# Django TypeError: logout() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I don't understand why this url is giving me an error:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

...
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout(next_page=reverse_lazy("dashboard:operations_login")), name="operations_logout"),
...
```

The error is:

> Django TypeError: logout() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the logout view directly in your url definition.

If you need to pass arguments, you should do so in a separate dictionary:

```
url(r'^logout/$',
    auth_views.logout,
    {'next_page': reverse_lazy("dashboard:operations_login")},
    name="operations_logout"),
```